# How do I add a public script to Prefab?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an empty game object in the hierarchy as shown below:
[image: Hierarchy].

It has a script and I want to do reach with my prefab which is
[image: prefab]

How can I do it?

Comment: What do you mean when you say `I want to do reach with my prefab`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drag your prefab and make it child to your Empty Game Object (who have script on him, will affect him too).
I always do this for onClick, for scenes and works great.
Tell me if made it.